Problem with setting up in app purchases with flutter
I'm trying to set up a subscription system in my flutter application but I have a recurring error that I can't fix.
My subscription window is well sheet with the different plans and when I click to buy the sandbox opens but when paying I always have the following error :
***Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Cannot finish a purchasing transaction' ***First throw call stack: (0x19af2269c 0x1981e32e4 0x19b01d408 0x1c84f7e48 0x10776fb24 0x10776d968 0x10777ee18 0x10777f100 0x107779440 0x10cf8c4c8 0x10c9f9794 0x109ce8a30 0x109cea71c 0x109cfade8 0x109cfa9a4 0x19aef60d4 0x19aef32f8 0x19aef2728 0x1e79971c4 0x19da541fc 0x19db02984 0x104c25174 0x1c158aec8) libc++abi: terminating due to uncaught exception of type NSException

Here is my purchasing system
class BillingService extends ChangeNotifier {
  final InAppPurchase _inAppPurchase = InAppPurchase.instance;
  List<ProductDetails> _products = [];
  final SupabaseClient _supabase = Supabase.instance.client;
  StreamSubscription<List<PurchaseDetails>>? _subscription;
  bool _isAvailable = false;
  final Map<String, bool> _savingSubscriptions = {};
  Set<String> _completedTransactions = {};

  List<ProductDetails> get products => _products;
  bool get isAvailable => _isAvailable;

  final StreamController<PurchaseStatus> _purchaseStatusController = StreamController<PurchaseStatus>.broadcast();
  Stream<PurchaseStatus> get purchaseStatusStream => _purchaseStatusController.stream;

  BillingService() {
    _initialize();
  }

  Future<void> _initialize() async {
    _isAvailable = await _inAppPurchase.isAvailable();
    if (_isAvailable) {
      await _getProducts();
      await clearTransactions();
      _subscription = _inAppPurchase.purchaseStream.listen(_onPurchaseUpdate, onDone: _updateStreamOnDone, onError: _updateStreamOnError);
    }
    notifyListeners();
  }

  Future<void> clearTransactions() async {
  final transactions = await SKPaymentQueueWrapper().transactions();
  for (var transaction in transactions) {
    if (transaction.transactionState == SKPaymentTransactionStateWrapper.purchased ||
        transaction.transactionState == SKPaymentTransactionStateWrapper.failed ||
        transaction.transactionState == SKPaymentTransactionStateWrapper.restored) {
      await SKPaymentQueueWrapper().finishTransaction(transaction);
    } else {
      print("Transaction ${transaction.transactionIdentifier} dans l'état ${transaction.transactionState} - ne peut pas être terminée");
    }
  }
}

  Future<void> _handlePendingPurchases(PurchaseDetails purchaseDetails) async {
  if (purchaseDetails.status == PurchaseStatus.purchased || 
      purchaseDetails.status == PurchaseStatus.restored) {
    if (purchaseDetails.pendingCompletePurchase && 
        !_completedTransactions.contains(purchaseDetails.purchaseID)) {
      try {
        await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1)); // Ajout d'un court délai
        await _saveSubscriptionToSupabase(purchaseDetails);
        if (purchaseDetails.pendingCompletePurchase) {
          await InAppPurchase.instance.completePurchase(purchaseDetails);
          _completedTransactions.add(purchaseDetails.purchaseID!);
        }
      } catch (e) {
        print("Erreur lors de la finalisation de la transaction : $e");
      }
    }
  } 
}

  Future<void> _getProducts() async {
    Set<String> ids = {GeneralVariables.storeKeyyYearly, GeneralVariables.storeKeyMonthly};
    ProductDetailsResponse response = await _inAppPurchase.queryProductDetails(ids);
    _products = response.productDetails;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void _onPurchaseUpdate(List<PurchaseDetails> purchaseDetailsList) {
    purchaseDetailsList.forEach((PurchaseDetails purchaseDetails) async {
      print("Mise à jour de l'achat - Status: ${purchaseDetails.status}");
      print("Mise à jour de l'achat - ProductID: ${purchaseDetails.productID}");
      print("Mise à jour de l'achat - PurchaseID: ${purchaseDetails.purchaseID}");
      print("Mise à jour de l'achat - TransactionDate: ${purchaseDetails.transactionDate}");
      print("Mise à jour de l'achat - PendingCompletePurchase: ${purchaseDetails.pendingCompletePurchase}");

      switch (purchaseDetails.status) {
        case PurchaseStatus.pending:
          print("Achat en attente");
          break;
        case PurchaseStatus.error:
          print("Erreur d'achat: ${purchaseDetails.error}");
          await _handlePendingPurchases(purchaseDetails);
          break;
        case PurchaseStatus.purchased:
        case PurchaseStatus.restored:
          print("Achat réussi ou restauré");
          await _handlePendingPurchases(purchaseDetails);
          break;
        case PurchaseStatus.canceled:
          print("Achat annulé");
          break;
      }
    });
  }

  Future<void> _saveSubscriptionToSupabase(PurchaseDetails purchaseDetails) async {
    print("Début de _saveSubscriptionToSupabase pour ${purchaseDetails.purchaseID}");
    final userId = _supabase.auth.currentUser?.id;
    if (userId == null) {
      print("User is not authenticated");
      return;
    }

    // Vérifier si on est déjà en train de sauvegarder cet abonnement
    if (_savingSubscriptions[purchaseDetails.purchaseID] == true) {
      print("Sauvegarde déjà en cours pour cet abonnement");
      return;
    }

    _savingSubscriptions[purchaseDetails.purchaseID!] = true;

    try {
      // Vérifier si un abonnement existe déjà
      final existingSubscriptions = await _supabase
          .from('subscriptions')
          .select()
          .eq('user_id', userId)
          .eq('status', 'active');

      if (existingSubscriptions.isNotEmpty) {
        // Mettre à jour l'abonnement existant
        await _supabase
            .from('subscriptions')
            .update({
              'subscription_id': purchaseDetails.purchaseID,
              'platform': defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.iOS ? 'apple' : 'google',
              'start_date': DateTime.now().toIso8601String(),
              'expiry_date': _calculateExpiryDate(purchaseDetails.productID).toIso8601String(),
            })
            .eq('user_id', userId)
            .eq('status', 'active');
        print("Abonnement existant mis à jour dans Supabase");
      } else {
        // Insérer un nouvel abonnement
        final subscriptionData = {
          'user_id': userId,
          'subscription_id': purchaseDetails.purchaseID,
          'platform': defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.iOS ? 'apple' : 'google',
          'status': 'active',
          'start_date': DateTime.now().toIso8601String(),
          'expiry_date': _calculateExpiryDate(purchaseDetails.productID).toIso8601String(),
        };

        final response = await _supabase
            .from('subscriptions')
            .insert(subscriptionData);
        
        if (response.error != null) {
          print("Failed to save subscription to Supabase. Error: ${response.error!.message}");
        } else {
          print("Nouvel abonnement sauvegardé dans Supabase avec succès");
        }
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print("Exception while saving subscription to Supabase: $e");
    } finally {
      _savingSubscriptions[purchaseDetails.purchaseID!] = false;
    }
    print("Fin de _saveSubscriptionToSupabase pour ${purchaseDetails.purchaseID}");
  }

  DateTime _calculateExpiryDate(String productId) {
    // Implement your logic to calculate expiry date based on the product ID
    // For example:
    if (productId == GeneralVariables.storeKeyyYearly) {
      return DateTime.now().add(const Duration(days: 365));
    } else if (productId == GeneralVariables.storeKeyMonthly) {
      return DateTime.now().add(const Duration(days: 30));
    }
    // Default to 1 month if unknown
    return DateTime.now().add(const Duration(days: 30));
  }

  void _updateStreamOnDone() {
    _subscription?.cancel();
  }

  void _updateStreamOnError(dynamic error) {
    // Handle error here
  }

  Future<void> buy(ProductDetails product) async {
  try {
    print("Préparation de l'achat");
    await clearTransactions();  // Nettoyer les transactions en attente avant un nouvel achat
      
    final purchaseParam = PurchaseParam(productDetails: product);
    print("PurchaseParam créé : ${purchaseParam.productDetails.id}");

    print("Tentative d'achat pour ${product.id}");
    var transactions = await SKPaymentQueueWrapper().transactions();
    transactions.forEach((skPaymentTransactionWrapper) {
        SKPaymentQueueWrapper().finishTransaction(skPaymentTransactionWrapper);
    });
    final bool success = await _inAppPurchase.buyNonConsumable(purchaseParam: purchaseParam);
    if (success) {
        print("Achat initié avec succès pour ${product.id}");
      } else {
        print("L'achat n'a pas été initié pour ${product.id}");
        throw Exception("L'achat n'a pas pu être initié");
      }
  } catch (e) {
      print('Exception dans buy : $e');
      if (e is SKError) {
        print('SKError code: ${e.code}, message: ${e.domain}');
      }
      rethrow;
    }

}

  Future<void> restorePurchases() async {
    await _inAppPurchase.restorePurchases();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _subscription?.cancel();
    _purchaseStatusController.close();
    super.dispose();
  }
}

class ExamplePaymentQueueDelegate implements SKPaymentQueueDelegateWrapper {
  @override
  bool shouldContinueTransaction(SKPaymentTransactionWrapper transaction, SKStorefrontWrapper storefront) {
    return true;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldShowPriceConsent() {
    return false;
  }
}

I need your help I understand the mistake but I can't solve it
